# Variable changed before the fact, can you explain this Chrome V8 behavior?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I was writing a javascript program and running it in Chrome 7, when I encountered some strange behavior. Now, in my code, with all the other stuff going on, it took me some time to figure out it wasn't me.

I have distilled the essence of the code below.

```
<html>

<script>

var data = [1,2,3,4,5];

var data_copy = [];

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    data_copy.push(data[i]);
}

console.log("Printing before:");
console.log(data_copy);

//alert(data_copy);

console.log("------------------------");

for (var i=0; i<data_copy.length; i++){
    data_copy[i] = data_copy[i] * 1000;
}

console.log("Printing after:");
console.log(data_copy);

</script>

</html>
```

When I run this on Chrome 7, I get the output that follows in the Javascript console:

```
Printing before:
[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
------------------------
Printing after:
[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
```

How come the first call to console.log prints the changed version of data_copy?

Now, if I uncomment the "alert" and run the same code, I get what you would normally expect:

```
Printing before:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
------------------------
Printing after:
[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
```

I also tried the code in node.js and I get the second (normal) output.

Any ideas?

Is this some JIT optimization gone awry?

Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: One guess is that the browser executes the call to log asynchronously, after the change. But why would it do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `console.log(data_copy)` to `console.log(String(data_copy))`.

`console.log` effectively sends the object by reference to Chrome's Console.  `alert` interrupts your script so the first logged `data_copy` gets rendered before the later modification; without, the entire script runs to completion before the console renders either `data_copy` reference.

Comment: I can see the console.log call being by reference, but why it doesn't get rendered immediately?

Comment: And why doesn't node.js, being essentially V8, give the same (wrong) output?

Comment: @foljs: The console isn't part of V8, it's part of Chrome.  And the JS thread in browsers is necessarily single-threaded, so the Chrome guys apparently decided that queuing up the object and waiting for the next time the JS thread is free was easier than figuring out how to get the JS thread to render a JS object from within arbitrary context.

Comment: @foljs: In all browsers, rendering happens only when js in not executing. It's how js was implemented in the first place: Netscape saw that they can squeeze a script interpreter between the traditional two phases of page loading `download->render` so that now we get `download->run_javascript->render`. It's also how things like `setTimeout` works: schedule the code to run in another `run_javascript` phase. The real issue here is that Chrome doesn't resolve the `console.log` arguments to string when it is called like how node.js does.

Comment: Also it should be noted that the javascript language, per se, doesn't include things like `document.getElementById` or `console.log`. Those are API that may or may not be supported by a specific implementation. Node.js for example does not support the DOM API so it doesn't have `document.getElementById`. And the DOM API is also not part of V8, it is part of Safari/Chrome/Webkit. V8 is just a javascript interpreter.

Comment: That's completely insance for debugging purposes.

Comment: One can also use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` (for <IE8 one needs to include [this](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), minimized/CDN-ized [here](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.min.js)). The bug is open here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316 (thanks to the other answer here, but that was a duplicate)
And +1 to ephemient definitely.

Comment: Also watch out for console.log and/or console.debug not being present (you may use [this](https://github.com/kayahr/console-shim), I haven't yet).

Answer (score 1):

See crbug.com/44720